# unable to connect Azure china log analytics from Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-log-analytics, grafana-api, grafana-variable

Able to connect to Azure rest of world Log analytics from Grafana but not to china Azure log analytics. Followed the same steps .

**Getting below error :**

1. Successfully queried the Azure Monitor service.
2. Azure Log Analytics: Cannot connect to Azure Log Analytics REST API.

Comment: Chakith - Are you still experiencing this issue or was it intermittent ? Can you please share if you have any additional details regarding the errors and setup.

Comment: still , facing the same issue. Getting "Azure Log Analytics: Cannot connect to Azure Log Analytics REST API." same error . not sure where to get proper logs in grafana app.

Comment: Chakith - Thanks for the confirmation, I have reached out to our internal product teams to better understand if there is any ongoing issue, will keep you updated. Thanks

Comment: thanks @bharathn-msft. will wait for your reply

Comment: Chakith - Got to know from the team that currently Azure China (part of National clouds) are not supported by Grafana yet. It is something in the backlog and planned by the teams involved in near future.

Comment: @bharathn-msft : thanks for the update. Once you start supporting azure china , Could you please inform me ?  do we have any tentative date ?

Comment: @bharathn-msft do you have any update here ?

Comment: Apologies for delayed response @Chakith , let me circle back with the respective team to know the latest status and get back to you.

Comment: @bharathn-msft sure

Comment: Please refer similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/27634#issuecomment-698184403)